.NET 8 Cors on Blazor web assembly standalone
I have Blazor web assembly standalone pProject in Visual Studio 2022.


Now when I want to use HttpClient and fetch some data from some website I get this error:

Access to fetch at 'https://tapi.bale.ai/someLink/getUpdates' from origin 'http://localhost:5246' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

How can I fix this CORS issue, and add header to host it?
i add Custome Header to IIS Express via applicationhost.config in .vs folder and now iis Express has header Access-Control-Allow-Origin=*
but not working ..


UPDATE
After investigation, if httpclient is used in the page to call third-party APIs, cross-domain problems will definitely occur.
So I recommend creating a proxy service, and the front-end page calls this service (providing url and verbs), and then this problem can be bypassed.
If tapi.bale.ai has other security certifications (such as CSRF), this solution may not work.
Here is the test code and result.
ProxyService.cs
using System.Net.Http.Json;

namespace BlazorApp1
{
    public class ProxyService
    {
        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

        public ProxyService(HttpClient httpClient)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
        }

        public async Task<string> SendRequestAsync(string url, string method, Dictionary<string, string> headers)
        {
            var proxyRequest = new ProxyRequest
            {
                Url = url,
                Method = method,
                Headers = headers
            };
            HttpResponseMessage response = null ;
            if (method == "GET") {
                response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
            }
            else if (method == "POST") {
                response = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/proxy", proxyRequest);
            }
           
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }

    public class ProxyRequest
    {
        public string? Url { get; set; }
        public string? Method { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string>? Headers { get; set; }
    }
}

Register it

Use it in Page
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    forecasts = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("sample-data/weather.json");

    var headers = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "User-Agent", "BlazorApp" }
    };

    result = await ProxyService.SendRequestAsync("https://localhost:7068/home/testcors1", "GET", headers);
}


If tapi.bale.ai is yours, you can follow below steps to add cors settings.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-8.0

Try to use BrowserRequestMode.NoCors and it works in my side.
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://tapi.bale.ai/someLink/getUpdates");
request.SetBrowserRequestMode(BrowserRequestMode.NoCors);
var response = await Http.SendAsync(request);
//var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();



not Cors Error anymore but Respond content is Empty !!!

@abbas-h Since I don't have token, I haven't check the content,will chek it tomorrow,please be patient.

thanks but i have only one standalone WASM PWA application without any server or somthing else ... this PWA call api on tapi.bale.ai and show somthing from it ... i dont have any server or backend part

@abbas-h what is tapi.bale.ai ? If you can't use the code above, you have to contact tapi.bale.ai help you, they should have ways to access their resources.

@abbas-h My solution includes simulating Postman to send requests through the ProxyService code level to bypass the CORS problem. We also analyzed that the fundamental problem of CORS is that tapi.bale.ai is not authorized to trust your URL. Hope you can find a correct way to implement this feature.
